# Moving the order of screen items with a mouse click

Tags: javascript

On my screen I have a simple list of items:

1. item 1
2. item 2
3. item 3

I have seen examples of where the user can click on an item and change its position in the list with the mouse.

Mu question is, how is this done? Is it a javascript function of sorts?

Comment: Changing the position of item in the list and Sorting the list are two different things. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you mean drag n drop? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: @ gentlebreeze Check the snippet posted in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery Ui library](https://jqueryui.com/) to accomplish this easily. Follow this snippet

```css
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { background:#aeaeae; margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>

 
<ul id="sortable">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the order of screen items with a mouse click

Try this: [jqueryui sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

Hope it helps